Flutter open in-app notification settings from phone settings
I noticed something recently. I opened the phone's SETTINGS->APPS->INSTAGRAM page and saw the "In-app notification settings Instagram" button in the notification settings. When you click on this button, Instagram's in-app notification settings page opens.
Can we do this in Flutter?
I'm currently using AwesomeNotification and FCM for notifications.

